# How does Redis checks if an element is a member of set or not?

Tags: redis

I have read online that Redis can say if an element is member of set or not in O(1) time. I want to know how Redis does this. What algorithm does Redis use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Redis Set is implemented internally in one of two ways: an `intset` or a `hashtable`. The intset is a special optimization for integer-only sets and uses the [`intsetSearch`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/intset.c#L115) function to search the set. This function, however, uses a binary search so that's actually technically O(logN). However, since the cardinallity of intsets is capped at a constant (the `set-max-intset-entries` configuration directive), we can assume O(1) accurately reflects the complexity here.

`hashtable` is used for a lot of things in Redis, including the implementation of Sets. It uses a hash function on the key to map it into a table (array) of entries - checking whether the hashed key value is in the array is straightforwardly done in O(1) in [`dictFind`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/deps/hiredis/dict.c#L243). The elements under each hashed key are stored as a linked list, so again you're basically talking O(N) to traverse it, but given the hash function extremely low probability for collisions (hmm, need some sort of citation here?) these lists are extremely short so we can safely assume it is effectively O(1).

Because of the above, [`SISMEMBER`](http://redis.io/commands/sismember)'s claim of being O(1) in terms of computational complexity is valid.